# failure or failing, how different?

Tags: gerunds

It is impossible to live without **failing.**

It is impossible to live without **failure.**

Which is proper when there is no following object of gerund? How different?

Comment: Both are possible. "Failure" is a nominalisation of "failing". There is no difference in meaning to speak of.

Comment: What are you trying to express? The first means that at some point in life you will fail. The second means that you can't live *unless* you fail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this context I prefer *failure*.

This is because "failure" could refer to an isolated incidence of failure as well as to multiple instances of failure, which is what I believe the sentence is trying to say - that over the course of your life you will encounter at least *some* failure(s), in any possible area of life.

"It is impossible to live without *failing*" reads as if you are *failing at life itself*.